# Routing to markdown files does shows page not found in Astro 9.5.1

Tags: routes, markdown, astrojs

```
---
// component imports
import MainLayout from "../../layouts/MainLayout.astro";
---

<MainLayout title="My Blog">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./post-1.md/"> post-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="./post-2.md/"> post-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="./post-3.md/"> post-3</a></li>
        <li><a href="./post-4.md/"> post-4</a></li>
        <li><a href="./post-5.md/"> post-5</a></li>
        <li><a href="./post-6.md/"> post-6</a></li>
    </ul>
</MainLayout>
```

file structure: [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkDKF.png)

Astro version 9.5.1

http://localhost:3000/blog/post-1.md/ shows page not found instead of showing the markdown file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to include the `.md` extension in the URL — this is stripped away for you by Astro, so that for example `src/pages/blog/post-1.md` becomes available at `http://localhost:3000/blog/post-1/`.